# Auto heaphone connecting problem

Tags: sound, headphones

Whenever I start my Ubuntu 18.04 laptop it's getting connected with headphone mode and there is no sound, but I've never connected to headphones since starting. I've also restarted my laptop to see that it solves the problem or not. It's working but again after some time it gets connected to the headphones automatically even though no headphones are physically connected.